# Using count function but having multiple fields in select statement to see more data

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 
    eq_locations.equipment,eq_locations.description, 
    eq_locations.marked_as_deleted count(wo_work_order.equipment)
 FROM  
    eq_locations, wo_work_order 
where 
    eq_locations.equipment=wo_work_order.equipment and 
    eq_locations.plant='908' and eq_locations.marked_as_deleted = '0'
group by 
    eq_locations.equipment
order by 
    eq_locations.equipment
```

The error I am getting is

> 'Error at line 2 ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'.

When I run the following query I get the equipment and the number of times it was used in the 2nd table (wo_work_order), but I need the description and the marked_as_deleted fields too from the first table (eq_locations)...

```
select eq_locations.equipment, count(wo_work_order.equipment) from eq_locations
left outer join wo_work_order
on eq_locations.equipment = wo_work_order.equipment
where eq_locations.plant='908'
group by eq_locations.equipment
order by eq_locations.equipment
```

Comment: Missing `,` between `marked_as_deleted count(wo_`?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding the missing comma `,` before the `count(wo_work_order.equipment)`, you need to add `eq_locations.description` and     `eq_locations.marked_as_deleted` in your group by clause.

```
select 
    eq_locations.equipment,eq_locations.description, 
    eq_locations.marked_as_deleted, count(wo_work_order.equipment)
 FROM  
    eq_locations, wo_work_order 
where 
    eq_locations.equipment=wo_work_order.equipment and 
    eq_locations.plant='908' and eq_locations.marked_as_deleted = '0'
group by 
    eq_locations.equipment, eq_locations.description, eq_locations.marked_as_deleted
order by 
    eq_locations.equipment
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JOIN ON`  syntax for joins. Do not use `a,b` syntax. Also, prefer simple table aliases than using the whole table names everywhere. I think you need the second query with `LEFT JOIN` to get 0 count for missing equipment in `wo_work_order` table. This query should work fine.

```
 SELECT  e.equipment,
         e.description,
         e.marked_as_deleted,
         COUNT(w.equipment)
FROM     eq_locations e LEFT OUTER JOIN wo_work_order w
ON e.equipment=w.equipment
AND      e.plant='908'
AND      e.marked_as_deleted = '0'
GROUP BY e.equipment,
         e.description,
         e.marked_as_deleted
ORDER BY e.equipment;
```